# angular 2 - how to import / inject a component during runtime

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

Let's say that there are two views of product, and I want to show one of those views based on user preferences.

I am thinking to have two views `<my-product>` maintained at two different folders and after user logged in, I want to import from a folder based on how the user prefers to view the product.

```
Folder 1
----MyProductComponent //exports MyProductComponent with selector <my-product></my-product>
Folder 2
----MyProductComponent //exports MyProductComponent with selector <my-product></my-product>   
App
----App.Component // here I would like to import the component at runtime from either folder 1 / 2 based on user preferences
```

Please share your insights on this. Are there any alternatives if this cannot be achieved at the component level (ex: at routing level).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just have an *ngIf on two elements that will swap based on the users preference?

```
<my-product1 *ngIf="userPref1"></my-product1>
<my-product2 *ngIf="!userPref1"></my-product2>
```

Where userPref1 is a variable (or function) located on App.Component that gets set by user input.

Then the user can state their preference and the application will swap the views based upon their input and you no longer need to deal with importing at run-time.

Comment: Thaks Joffutt, I thought about this, but I prefer not to change the main component (App.Component in this case). There could be many places that I may be using <my-product> and instead of changing all these places, I prefer to just create a preference folder (PREF2 - for example) and add a required view into it. I just hope if there is a way to import a component from a folder which path is only known during runtime..

Comment: Ok cool.. now I got an idea.. may be create one more component that exports with <my-product> and add required if or switch cases (just like Husein mentioned) and use that component elsewhere.. so I can only change at one place... I will mark yours as an answer.. Thanks for your input..

Answer (score 1):

You should use `[ngSwitch]` based on the user's preference and then in `*ngSwitchCase` load that particular component. In reality, you are not lazy loading your components. They are all preloaded, but you just use Angular's DOM manipulation methods to show or hide one component or the other.

For example:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="someUserPreference">
    <div *ngSwitchCase="grid">
        <my-grid-list></my-grid-list>
    </div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase="card">
        <my-card-view-grid></my-card-view-grid>
    </div>
    <div *ngSwitchDefault>
        <!-- Incorrect preference, let's show grid as a fallback -->
        <my-grid-list></my-grid-list>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically, when a user changes their preference, this will be reflected in the code. Either they change the preference via a button, radio button, or whatever, you need to store that value in `someUserPreference` variable or property that will be used in the switch statement.

Comment: Thanks Husein for your inputs, Joffutt also shared similar views and I marked his as an answer. Thanks again!!

Comment: No worries @RaviSamanthapudi. It's important that your question was answered.